# randomize time for looping task in discord

Tags: python, random, discord, discord.py

I have this code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import tasks    
client = discord.Client()
@tasks.loop(minutes=1)
    async def test():
        channel = client.get_channel(MY_CHANNEL)
        await channel.send("hello")

    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        test.start()
```

Which basically sends every minute a hello message in my channel. But is it also possible to randomize the time between the message sent. Like for one loop it is 3 and in the other 5...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing so would be using the `current_loop` attribute and the `change_interval` method:

```py
@tasks.loop(minutes=1)
async def test():
    channel = client.get_channel(MY_CHANNEL)
    await channel.send("hello")

    if test.current_loop % 2 == 0:
        test.change_interval(minutes=3)
    else:
        test.change_interval(minutes=1)
```

It simply changes the interval to 3 minutes every two iterations, then resets it back to the original 1 minute

#### Reference:

- [`Loop.current_loop`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html#discord.ext.tasks.Loop.current_loop)
- [`Loop.change_interval`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html#discord.ext.tasks.Loop.change_interval)